# How to get simple Webpack bundle up and running using webpack-dev-server

Tags: browser, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-scripts

I am just scratching the surface of building my development environment with webpack, webpack-dev-server, and hot module reloading. I want to eventually be able to add react components to a primarily static site (so that I get the SEO benefit of having crawlable html. I've decided that I will not use Gulp or Grunt, instead I'll solely use npm scripts to run shell commands for the development, testing, building, and publishing.

Returning to the title/topic of this question. I have not been able to get browsers to read my bundle.js file generated by webpack. I've boiled my library down to the simplest `index.html` and `index.js` that you can see below.

The error output to the console is:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):7)
> ```

The emitted `bundle.js` file must be where the error is:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

const handleClick = () => {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
};

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

My `index.html` file:

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Simple JS demo</p>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick='handleClick()'>Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My `index.js` file:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!"
}
```

My `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: '/home/andrew/code/my-site/public',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

My `npm start` script:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base public/"
  }
```

I have webpack installed globally so I can generate the `bundle.js` file in the `public/` folder with the command `webpack`, though `npm start` emits the `bundle.js` file anyways.

There's got to be some simple error that I'm making.

**solution via @Marek Takac:**
The error here is that the scope of the `handleClick()` function is not global. This can be remedied by exporting the module from within the `index.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  handleClick: handleClick
}
```

and using webpack's [output.library and output.libraryTarget](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) options to define a global variable.

See also webpack's [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're webpack bundle seems to be OK. The problem is in your code. `handleClick` function is undefined because you are calling it from global environment. You basically try to call `window.hanldeClick` but you defined your `handleClick` function in totally different scope. Webpack puts the function into separate closure to prevent polluting your global environment. I would suggest you to go through some webpack / react tutorials, guides and documentation. However if you want just to test that your setup works correctly logging something out to the console from your `index.js` file. Alternatively I think your code should work if you change `const handleClick` to `window.handleClick` (although I never tried something like this).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't believe that scope is the problem here though. Replacing my bundle.js in the public folder with index.js (and the script `src=` in the html file) and then just opening the index.html file in the browser (instead of serving it up with webpack-dev-server), the script works. I am not using react just yet, and I have combed the webpack docs fairly thoroughly...

Comment: Okay, so what happens if you `console.log` something from your `index.js` file? Does it actually logs anything to the console?

Comment: @Drew2 it is an issue with scope. Check you bundle.js and you'll see that whole file is new scope without access to globals. If you'll actually try what I suggest in my answer you'll see it works :)

Comment: my apologies, you are correct, needed to refamiliarize myself with JS closures. I will update my question with a solution.